# Store html form values in android storage

Tags: javascript, android

How is it possible to store html form input values, via javascript in native android storage?

Comment: Probably. Where is the form (displayed in a WebView in your app, or is this a webpage you're hoping will interact with the phone) and why do you want to store it on the phone?

Comment: The form comes from some bundled html files located on the assets folder, i need to save it on the device, since this targets some android tablet which will be used for on store marketing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a javascript interface to get the form values, and then filewriter to write it to the sd card.

Javascript Interface Android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

FileWriter:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html